How to apply anime.js keyframes in A-Frame
In this example, we can see how keyframes work in anime.js. Inspired by this answer and A-Frame doc, I tried to apply it with the following code without success:
/* global AFRAME */

AFRAME.registerComponent('animation-test', {
    schema: {

    },

    init: function () {
        this.el.setAttribute('animation__001', {
            'property': 'position',
            // 'to': { x: -0.47, y: 1.73, z: -0.3 },
            'keyframes': [
                { x: -0.47, y: 1.63, z: -0.5 },
                { x: -0.47, y: 1.73, z: -0.5 },
                { x: -0.47, y: 1.73, z: -0.3 },
            ],
            'duration': 4000,
            'startEvents': 'startanim001'
        });
        this.el.emit('startanim001', null, false);
    },

I expected the animation to take 4 seconds, and in that time to move the object to different coordinates.
Or is there another way to use keyframes?
Thank you in advance.
